# setInterval() halts while code is executing

Tags: javascript, asynchronous, setinterval

I was under the impression that `setInterval(function, delay)` would schedule a call to `function` every `delay` milliseconds. It would repeatedly do this until `clearInterval()` was called. However, it seems I'm missing something.

I have the following sample page. The intent is simple: have the text switch from *Loading* -> *Loading.* -> *Loading..* every second. Here's a sample of the loop working as expected:

```js
    $(document).ready(function(){
        $('#loading_icon').html("Loading");
        loop = setInterval(function() {
            updateText();
        }, 1000);
    });

    function updateText() {
        loadingText = $('#loading_icon').html();
        $('#loading_icon').html(loadingText == "Loading"  ? "Loading."  : 
                                loadingText == "Loading." ? "Loading.." : 
                                "Loading");
    }
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="loading_icon">Loading</div>
```

Nothing to it. The issue is that it doesn't execute this code so long as JavaScript is doing anything else. I've set the up following example:

```js
    $(document).ready(function(){
        $('#loading_icon').html("Loading");
        loop = setInterval(function() {
            updateText();
        }, 1000);

        for(i = 0; i < 100000; i++)
           var a = fib(i);  // Just an arbitrary method to simulate work
    });

    function fib(n){
        var a=1,b=0,t;while(n>=0){t=a;a=a+b;b=t;n--;}return b;
    }

    function updateText() {
        loadingText = $('#loading_icon').html();
        $('#loading_icon').html(loadingText == "Loading"  ? "Loading."  : 
                                loadingText == "Loading." ? "Loading.." : 
                                "Loading");
    }
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="loading_icon">Loading</div>
```

Ideally, the text would be changing while we were doing all this work (that's the whole reason I'm writing this "loading" feature, after all). However, it seems that no calls to `updateText()` are being called until JS has nothing better to do.

What am I missing here? Is there any way to accomplish what I'm after?

Comment: Have you looked in nextTick/requestAnimationFrame for executing your function in the next available frame.

Comment: JS is single-threaded, you cannot do multiple things at once. Yes, it *schedules* it after one second, but the scheduled function won't run.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, it still works - the problem is that your loop over `fib` is running first, then `setInterval` is running later. You can decrease the loop length to see it working perfectly:

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('#loading_icon').html("Loading");
  loop = setInterval(function() {
    updateText();
  }, 1000);

  for (i = 0; i < 100000; i++)
    var a = fib(i); // Just an arbitrary method to simulate work
});

function fib(n) {
  var a = 1,
    b = 0,
    t;
  while (n >= 0) {
    t = a;
    a = a + b;
    b = t;
    n--;
  }
  return b;
}

function updateText() {
  loadingText = $('#loading_icon').html();
  $('#loading_icon').html(loadingText == "Loading" ? "Loading." :
    loadingText == "Loading." ? "Loading.." :
    "Loading");
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="loading_icon">Loading</div>
```

Unfortunately, you can't make an extremely long loop and a `setInterval` run at exactly the same time.

Comment: I think there's a misunderstanding. I'm trying to have my loading text update *while* this work is being done. Your example just has the work finish in a fraction of a second, then have the loop begin once it's finished. That's not quite what I'm after.

Comment: Sorry, but my answer shows that JavaScript can only run one thing at once - the loop runs first, and then the `setInterval` begins. I'll edit my answer.

Answer (score 0):

Your understanding of `setInterval()` seems to be correct. It should not be halting code outside of its callback function. Most likely your code is getting caught up somewhere else.

As for accomplishing what you're trying to do, your solution should work but it's not a very elegant way of manipulating the DOM. I see that you're using jQuery, which has pretty robust [animation functionality](http://api.jquery.com/animate/). I would look into using something like this.